# C# Get the content without the header from a POST request

Tags: c#, linq, xmlhttprequest

I have a response sent from my website to my program. Here's what it looks like:

```
POST /login.html/signup HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.75
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 450
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Origin: http://192.168.1.75
Authorization: 1497742211491
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://192.168.1.75/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

`%7B%22name%22%3A%22Adola%22%2C%22telp%22%3A%22%22%2C%22agen%22%3A%22pribadi%22%2C%22alamatagen%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hp%22%3A%22%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22Adola%40gmail.com%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%22ABCDEFG%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22123456%22%2C%22pcidses%22%3A%22ABCDEFG%22%2C%22pcidperm%22%3A%221497742211491%22%2C%22imgsrc%22%3A%22%22%2C%22capcode%22%3A%22dsiauh%22%2C%22ckperm%22%3A%22%22%2C%22cknw%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ckcd1%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ckcd2%22%3A%22%22%7D`

It's a POST request sending some some user data from the web browser to the program. My goal is only to get the URI encoded data from above. Currently my inefficient way is by using this code:

```
 string[] splitted = rawResponse.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
 //int result = 0;
 string aa = null;

 for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
 {
    if (splitted[i].Contains("%"))
    {
        aa = aa + splitted[i];
    }
 }

 string s = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(aa);
 Console.WriteLine(s);
```

In which the rawResponse is the request above. The result printed is this:

`{"name":"Adola","telp":"","agen":"pribadi","alamatagen":"","hp":"","email":"Adola@gmail.com","userid":"ABCDEFG","password":"123456","pcidses":"ABCDEFG","pcidperm":"1497742211491","imgsrc":"","capcode":"dsiauh","ckperm":"","cknw":"","ckcd1":"","ckcd2":""}`

The problem is when the request header (not the content) includes '%' it will give me an error eg. `GET /%USER%/12865`. How do I efficiently without any problem get the content. Thank you!

Comment: How do you send your request from your website to your program? What kind of program you have? windows app? another web app?

Comment: It's a console app. I am using the `Socket` class to make the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you skip the header and directly take care of the body. Use this code if your source object doesn't provide the mean to access the body directly:

```
string[] splitted = rawResponse.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
string aa = null;
if (splitted[splitted.Length-1].Contains("%"))
{
    aa = aa + splitted[splitted.Length-1];
}

string s = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(aa);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Ok, It make sense now. Let me test it

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly even with `%` on the header.